# angular 4 image src binding issue

Tags: angular

I am using angular 4 and is stuck at a point. I am using below code in html component to display data in a table:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th width="22%">Description</th>
      <th>Requested <br> Date</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th width="15%">Status change Date</th>
      <th width="10%">User ID</th>
      <th width="31%">Comments</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let orm of ormData">
      <td>{{orm.code}}</td>
      <td class="specialWidth">{{orm.description}}</td>
      <td>{{orm.reqDate}}</td>
      <td>{{orm.status}}</td>
      <td>{{orm.statusChngDate}}</td>
      <td>{{orm.userId}}</td>
      <td>{{orm.comments}}</td>
      <td><img src={{orm.img}} alt="delete" height=30px" width="30px"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and this is the ormData from ts component:

```
ormData = [{
'code':'AP1',
'description':'AP Translated and attested by SM',
'reqDate':'29/11/2016',
'status':'pending',
'statusChngDate':'13/12/2016',
'userId':'User ID',
'comments':'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui ipsam in.',
'img':'assets/icons/deleteGrey.svg'
```

}];

Now in my output am getting all data as expected except for the image. Instead of the image text content `<img src="assets/icons/deleteGrey.svg" alt="delete" height=30px" width="30px">` is being displayed.

Kindly let me know how can I get my image displayed in the output.

Comment: I see you have `'img':'assets/icons/deleteGrey.svg'`. Can you use a .svg extension with `<img />`?

Comment: Nevermind.. I guess thats valid. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Do you mean that the actual text `"<img..."` is being displayed?

Comment: yes, actual text "<img..."  was getting displayed. Seems the correct syntax to use here is <img [src]='orm.img' ...>
After that it is working properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing "" at the height attribute,

```
 <td><img [src]='orm.img'  height="30px" width="30px">
 </td>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/c9O1L0ls4OnBsKwvNl9B?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks for your quick response @Sajeetharan. I tried your method but still getting this in the output instead of the image

<img [src]='orm.img' alt="delete" height=30px" width="30px">

Comment: still getting what ?

Comment: do you have a valid url?

Comment: yes, If I remove ngFor from the <tr> then image loads properly but if I keep the ngFor it doesn't

Comment: Are you really sure there's a difference between `[src]="foo"` and `src="{{foo}}"`?

Comment: check the attached demo

Comment: @torazaburo you can do either way

Comment: thanks @Sajeetharan it worked, I was missing the quotes in the height attribute.